# IIS App Pool stops when 32-bit is enabled

Tags: iis, windows-10, application-pool, iis-10

I have a brand new laptop with Windows 10 Professional. I have installed VS2019. I have also installed IIS. I have the default IIS setup, so just Default Web Site which when browsed goes to the default IIS page. I enable 32-bit mode on my DefaultAppPool. I then try to browse to the website again and I get a 503 error. The app pool has stopped.

I have seen numerous posts on the internet about attaching debuggers, writing log files, looking at the event viewer logs as well - but none of them are helping me. I have noticed that I can enable 32-bit and not assign any web application to it... then the app pool stays running. The second I assign a web application to the app pool it crashes (I set the Start Mode in the app pool advanced settings to Always Running in this instance)

I have created a new App Pool and tried the config again. If I look at event viewer logs, I get this:

[image: Logs]

[image: Error Details]

[image: Warning Details]

I have also tried uninstalling IIS, deleting the inetsrv folder in system32, deleting inetpub and then reinstalling IIS.

I have also tried looking at the applicationHost.config file to try to pick up anything weird in there and everything looks good.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
These are the Friendly views:
Error:
[image]

Warning:
[image]

I have downloaded the Microsoft Error Lookup tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100432)

According to this article I should take the value after the colon (:) and use it as a parameter on the Microsoft Error Tool (http://intelligentsystemsmonitoring.com/knowledgebase/internet-information-services/event-id-iis-worker-process-availability-21961/). I have done this for both values (70050780 and 80070570). Here are the outputs:
[image]

Is this anything to go on? If so what can I do to fix these errors? I don't know what file it's trying to access or which directory is corrupt. I have given Everyone and App Pool users access to inetpub to test it out but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can only assign 32 bit web apps to a 32 bit application pool, or the pool will crash like that. So to learn more about the crash, study your web app.

Comment: Yes I agree and I know this. The thing is that I have a fresh install of Windows 10 and IIS. I have not loaded any other websites - just the default web site that comes with IIS. So the default web site MUST run even if I enable 32-bit on the app pool. I have tested this out on another laptop as well to confirm before writing this comment.

Comment: No, you don't have a "fresh install". If you said you "have installed VS2019," I think there can be quite a lot of other stuffs installed already. A true fresh install can only come directly from Microsoft's Windows installation media.

Comment: Ok. Sure. But what I'm trying to do is not out of the norm for a development environment.

Comment: I tried setting the application pool to 32-bit, but it worked fine. Generally speaking, even if the application pool is set to 32-bit, it will not affect the loading of the default website. Your question is strange, so I suggest you raise a support ticket.https://support.microsoft.com/